# P or NP-Complete? (concerning 2-CNF formulas)

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

I have two languages that I want to either prove is in P or NP-complete.

1) 2-CNF formulas where there exists an assignment that satisfies the 3/4 of the first 1000 clauses and all of the rest.

2) 2-CNF formulas where there exists an assignment that satisfies the all of the first 1000 clauses and 3/4 of the rest.

Intuitively, I want to say that 1) is P and 2) is NP-complete, but I am not sure and don't know how to prove my intuition. I am assuming that 2SAT is what I will need to reduce from for 1). If 2) is in P, then 2SAT should also be a good candidate, but I don't know if it's in P.

Comment: Please note that we now have a http://cs.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: @J.D.: cs.stackexchange.com is currently in private beta.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** is clearly in P -- actually it is solvable in linear time, since there are only $\binom{1000}{750}=O(1)$ different ordinary 2SAT problems to try, and each of these can be checked in linear time.

**(2)** is NP-complete, by reduction from the known NP-hard [MAX-2-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Maximum-2-satisfiability) problem which asks to recognize those $(A,k)$ such that $A$ is a set of 2-clauses with a $k$-element satisfiable subset.

Given $(A,k)$, pick a fresh variable $x_0$ and construct an input to your problem (2) consisting of

- 1000 copies of the clause $x_0\lor x_0$ -- these will be the 1000 clauses that must always be satisfied.
- the clauses in $A$.
- $3|A|-k$ copies of $x_0 \lor \neg x_0$ (these are automatically satisfied).
- $k$ copies of $\neg x_0 \lor \neg x_0$ (these can never be satisfied).

This gives an instance of (2) that must answer true exactly if $k$ clauses in $A$ can be satisfied simultaneously.

If you don't like clauses such as $x_0\lor x_0$ where the two *literals* are identical, they can be avoided without much trouble. On the other hand, the reduction breaks down if you restrict problem (2) to be about formulas that don't repeat any *clause*. I don't know if MAX-2-SAT is still NP-hard under restrictions that allow the reduction to be salvaged then.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many variables are involved in the first 1000 clauses?

Comment: If you mean literals, there are 2000 literals. There can be many different variables since variables can be reused in between clauses of CNF formulas.

Comment: Wait, so for 1), since the number of variables in the first 1000 clauses is upperbounded by 2000, we can find a way to satisfy 3/4 of them in P time. To satisfy the rest is the same as normal 2SAT?
Then for 2), finding the satisfying assignment for the first 1000 is clearly in P time, but then finding 3/4 of the rest, I am not sure.
Am I understanding what you are getting at or am I just completely off?

Comment: You got the gist of it.

Comment: So is finding a way to satisfy 3/4 of an unknown number of clauses in P time? 
Maybe it is in P time to just see how many clauses there are and then to satisfy them is just in P time as well since we can find out how many there are?

Comment: It is always possible to satisfy at least 3/4 of the clauses, if each one contains exactly two distinct literals. This may or may not be helpful in your case.

Comment: But since there is no way of figuring out if the literals are distinct, we can't really say that can we?